# selecting SIFT descriptors from a lot such that chosen are invariant to rotation

Tags: sift, descriptor

I have a collection of images (size 512x512) of different objects.
I get approx 6k SIFT descriptors in each image.
My aim is to choose few (say n) among them.
If I rotate the image by any angle then I want a method so that I am able to single out those 'n' descriptors.
If I replace part of an image with blank then I want the method to give me some out of those 'n' descriptors.
Please suggest.
Also, is it a good idea to sort descriptors by their response value and choose the top few . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sift is *not* rotation invariant, but you will not find a correlation between a descriptor(s) and an angle.
2. Descriptors has location and a radius, you can just check for each of them if it within required rectangle
3. Its definitely a good idea from performance perspective to chose descriptors with best response.

Comment: i am able to find out x,y coordinate of descriptor but what does 'radius' mean ? Is it that it tells the nearby area of the point that is required to detect that descriptor .

Comment: It looks like i messed different descriptors. SIFT does depends on rotation. SURF is rotation invariant.

Comment: SIFT is not an issue.
My biggest problem is that how can I select few points from a scattered distribution such that they get selected (at least partially) even when  a part of distribution is removed or the distribution is rotated/scaled.

Comment: Are you looking for matching key points in all of your images? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i need to create a database of image with few SIFT descriptors.When I get a test image I will match against those few SIFT descriptors.

Comment: thanks igorushi . The paper mentions about reducing SIFT descriptor to as low as 16 bit and calculating hamming distance from original euclidean .
Is there an implementation code ?